How to setup SSL for Weblogic java client without env variables
I'm using WebLogic Server 14.1.1 Thin T3 Jakarta client from Oracle's official website to consume messages from a WebLogic JMS queue. My problem is that the WebLogic server I need to consume from has a self-signed certificate, so when I try to consume using the T3S protocol, the connection fails.
I managed to get it to work by setting the javax.net.ssl.trustStore and javax.net.ssl.trustStorePassword environment variables. However, since this configuration causes the entire application to trust this certificate, I would like to configure it so that only the JMS connection factory uses my certificate as trusted, not the whole application. I tried a few approaches that I found (I commented them out in my attached code), but nothing worked for me. So, I would be glad for any information about how to set it up properly.
public class JmsConfig {


    @Bean
    public ConnectionFactory connectionFactory() throws NamingException {
        JndiObjectFactoryBean jndiObjectFactoryBean = new JndiObjectFactoryBean();
        jndiObjectFactoryBean.setJndiName("weblogic.jms.ConnectionFactory");
        jndiObjectFactoryBean.setJndiEnvironment(getEnvProperties());
        jndiObjectFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet();

        return (QueueConnectionFactory) jndiObjectFactoryBean.getObject();
    }

    @Bean
    public DefaultJmsListenerContainerFactory jmsListenerContainerFactory(ConnectionFactory connectionFactory) {
        DefaultJmsListenerContainerFactory factory = new DefaultJmsListenerContainerFactory();
        factory.setConnectionFactory(connectionFactory);
        JndiDestinationResolver jndiDestinationResolver = new JndiDestinationResolver();
        jndiDestinationResolver.setJndiEnvironment(getEnvProperties());
        factory.setDestinationResolver(jndiDestinationResolver);
        return factory;
    }
    
    private Properties getEnvProperties() {
        Properties envProperties = new Properties();
        envProperties.put(Context.INITIAL_CONTEXT_FACTORY, "weblogic.jndi.WLInitialContextFactory");
        envProperties.put(Context.PROVIDER_URL, serverUrl);
        envProperties.put(Context.SECURITY_PRINCIPAL, user);
        envProperties.put(Context.SECURITY_CREDENTIALS, password);

        // things that doesn't work
        // envProperties.put("weblogic.security.SSL.ignoreHostnameVerification", "true");
        // envProperties.put("java.protocol.handler.pkgs", "weblogic.net");
        // envProperties.put("weblogic.security.TrustKeyStore", "CustomTrust");
        // envProperties.put("weblogic.security.CustomTrustKeyStoreFileName", "\\C:\\cert\\mycert.p12");
        // envProperties.put("weblogic.security.CustomTrustKeyStorePassPhrase", "changeit");
        // envProperties.put("weblogic.security.CustomTrustKeyStoreType", "P12");

        // envProperties.put("weblogic.jndi.ssl.client.certificate", "\\C:\\cert\\mycert.p12");
        // envProperties.put("weblogic.jndi.ssl.client.key_password", "changeit");

        return envProperties;
    }

    @JmsListener
    ......
}


Does this answer your question? How to connect to a Weblogic JMS queue using t3s?

@Hakan54 I tried it and it doesn't work

You could try https://github.com/Hakky54/sslcontext-kickstart?tab=readme-ov-file#global-ssl-configuration I had a similar issue with MySQL java connector where I could not configure the ssl configuration. I have an example with mysql here: https://github.com/Hakky54/java-tutorials/tree/main/bypassing-overruling-ssl-configuration However, I am not sure whether this will work for your use case with Weblogic, but you can give it a try.
